What are the estimated savings to the median tax-payer if DOGE reduces spending by $2tn and savings are passed on proportionally?
It is suggested the Department of Government Efficiency could save \$2 Trillion in government spending annually (almost a third of current annual government spending ($6.5 Trillion).
Question
Theoretically, if these savings were realised and passed on immediately and proportionally1 across all US tax-payers, by how much (in dollars) would the median tax-payer's tax bill be reduced?
Note
To approximate the average per worker (an inferior metric to median) one could divide the $2tn savings among the US's 171m strong labor force: \$11,700 per worker. But average per worker may not be a sensible statistic since many workers don't pay that much tax in the first place, and tax-paid is probably right-skewed (similar to income).

1. i.e. same percentage reduction across every tax-payer's tax payable 

Seriously? And a "doge"-tag?

@MichaelGreinecker DOGE has some funny aspect to it but it’s essentially similar to the fed or treasury (just an important part of the machinery of govt with a specific role to play). E.g. Many countries have an approximate equivalent (for example in Australia there’s a ‘Productivity Commission’)

Did you see tags for these institutions in other countries? Are they run by donors too?

This is just a math question.
